# Conditional probability - unify 2 independent conditional probabilities

Tags: probability

I have a ball which can be black or white. There are two methods which can independently predict if the ball is black, each with a probability of success of  $90\%$. Assuming both methods predict the ball is black, what is the chance the ball is actually black?

In other words, $P(\text{Black} \mid A) = 0.9$, $P(\text{Black} \mid B) = 0.9$, $P(\text{Black} \mid A ∩ B) = $?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $C$ denote the event that the ball is black. Let $p$ denote the probability that the ball is black.

$P(C|AB)$

$=\frac{P(CAB)}{P(AB)}$

$=\frac{P(AB|C)P(C)}{P(AB)}$

$=\frac{P(A|C)P(B|C)P(C)}{P(AB)}$

Note that $A$ and $B$ are conditionally independent given $C$, but not otherwise.

The numerator is given by $0.9 \times 0.9 \times p = 0.81p$.

The denominator can be written as $P(AB) = P(AB|C)P(C) + P(AB|\bar{C})P(\bar{C})$ = $P(A|C)P(B|C)P(C) + P(A|\bar{C})P(B|\bar{C})P(\bar{C})$ = $0.81p + 0.01(1-p)$.

Putting it together:

$P(C|AB) = \frac{0.81p}{0.81p + 0.01(1-p)}$.

If the ball is equally likely to be black or white, you can plug in $p=0.5$ and get  $P(C|AB) = 81/82$.